# Quicksort Algorithm giving segmentation fault error

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I'm trying to create a program that takes a vector with 5 elements and sorts them according to their distances (what "distance" means is besides the point here).

But it gives me the "**segmentation fault**" error everytime I execute it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
char ID[8];
char Content[4];
int distance;

} DATA;


void sort(DATA *z, int l){

DATA p; //pivot
DATA t;
int aux=(l-1); //pivot's position
int i,j;

p.distance=z[l-1].distance;


if(l==1){return;}

for(i=0; i<l; i++){

    if((z[i].distance)<(p.distance)){

        continue;
    }


    if((z[i].distance)>(p.distance)){

        t=z[i];

            for(j=i; j<aux; j++){

                z[j]=z[j+1];

            }

            z[aux]=t;
            aux--;
    }

}


sort(z,aux-1);
sort(&z[aux+1],l-aux);

}

int main(){

DATA *z;
int l=5;
int i;

z=(DATA*)malloc(5*sizeof(DATA));

z[0].distance=5;
z[1].distance=1;
z[2].distance=4;
z[3].distance=3;
z[4].distance=2;

sort(z,l);

for(i=0; i<5; i++){

    printf("%d\n",z[i].distance);
}

free(z);

}
```

I don't see where the problem might be. Please help if you can.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Have you used a debugger? That is the right tool for the job. For starters it will tell you immediately and precisely which line of code causes the seg fault.

Comment: Which one do you recommend? Thanks for the quick response btw!

Comment: gdb if you are using linux.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling sort recursively without checking what the value of the second argument is.
Executing your code with gdb produced this output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400661 in sort (z=0x602010, l=-513) at main.c:21
21  p.distance=z[l-1].distance;
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400661 in sort (z=0x602010, l=-513) at main.c:21
#1  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-511) at main.c:51
#2  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-509) at main.c:51
#3  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-507) at main.c:51
#4  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-505) at main.c:51
#5  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-503) at main.c:51
#6  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-501) at main.c:51
#7  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-499) at main.c:51
#8  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-497) at main.c:51
#9  0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-495) at main.c:51
#10 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-493) at main.c:51
#11 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-491) at main.c:51
#12 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-489) at main.c:51
#13 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-487) at main.c:51
#14 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-485) at main.c:51
#15 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-483) at main.c:51
#16 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-481) at main.c:51
#17 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-479) at main.c:51
#18 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-477) at main.c:51
#19 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-475) at main.c:51
#20 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-473) at main.c:51
#21 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-471) at main.c:51
#22 0x000000000040077c in sort (z=0x602010, l=-469) at main.c:51
```

You can compile your code with debug symbols like this `gcc -g main.c`
Then execute it with gdb `gdb a.out` After it loads just type run to run it and you will see the segmentation fault. Type bt for the back trace.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious

```
sort(&z[aux+1],l-aux);
```

l is the length, aux +1 the new base index, so the new length should be l - aux -1

However as others have said, you need to debug / put in diagnostic printfs. It's hard to debug a function like that ion screen.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out by several comments , you could use gdb to find the location of the Segmentation Fault . I did that on your original code , and found that it breaks at line

```
p.distance=z[l-1].distance;  // statement 1
```

As pointed out by Malcolm , it happens because you are not passing in the the length of the arrays correctly in your recursive calls to sort function.The correct recursive calls should be (remember c arrays are zero-based)

```
sort(z,aux); // left half of the array , excluding the pivot
sort(&z[aux+1],l-aux-1); // right half of the array.
```

Furthermore the statement 1 should ideally be placed after you check ,

```
if(l <= 1){return;}
```

Notice  , how I changed the comparison from l == 1 to l <= 1 as you also have to check the case for l = 0 .Even after these changes , your loop for traversing the array , had some problems , which I tried to fix as best as I could while maintaining the original code structure. This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
char ID[8];
char Content[4];
int distance;

} DATA;


void sort(DATA *z, int l){

DATA p; //pivot
DATA t;
int aux=(l-1); //pivot's position
int i,j;




if(l <= 1){return;}
p.distance=z[l-1].distance;
for(i=0; i<l; i++){

if(i >= aux)
    break; // to avoid going over the right of pivot unnecessarily
if((z[i].distance)<(p.distance)){

    continue;
}


if((z[i].distance)>(p.distance)){

    t=z[i];

        for(j=i; j<aux; j++){

            z[j]=z[j+1];

        }

        z[aux]=t;
        aux--;
        i--; // You have changed the array and brought in a new element , 
       //and you should consider it too for comparison with pivot. 
}

}


sort(z,aux); // left half of the array , excluding the pivot
sort(&z[aux+1],l-aux-1); // right half of the array.

}

int main(){

DATA *z;
int l=5;
int i;

z=(DATA*)malloc(5*sizeof(DATA));

z[0].distance=5;
z[1].distance=1;
z[2].distance=4;
z[3].distance=3;
z[4].distance=2;

sort(z,l);

for(i=0; i<5; i++){

printf("%d\n",z[i].distance);
}

free(z);

}
```

But I would suggest that you consider writing the traversal loop differently as right now its moving around too many elements and is in fact O(n^2). While
using quicksort the desired behavior is that it be O(n) . I recommend looking up the algorithm in a good book like CLRS algorithm book.